# Saving data after navigating to a subpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, onclick, element

I have two problems regarding a certain js function.

The first one is to remember the color of the category after changing to another subpage.
deleting it when we go to another category and adding it to the one we clicked earlier. I was thinking about using sessionStorage, but I'm not sure if it's the optimal solution. I declare that I am a beginner.

```
var table = $("#header .top-menu a.dropdown-item");

console.log(table);

table.on('click', function (event) {
event.target.style.color="blue";
> });
```

The second problem is reading the elements of the list, but without their children. I want to keep only the a.dropdown-iteam elements, and the dropdown-submenu elements should not change.

Console.Log--->

```
0: a.dropdown-item
1: a.dropdown-item.dropdown-submenu
2: a.dropdown-item.dropdown-submenu
3: a.dropdown-item
4: a.dropdown-item.dropdown-submenu
5: a.dropdown-item.dropdown-submenu
6: a.dropdown-item
7: a.dropdown-item
8: a.dropdown-item
9: a.dropdown-item
length: 10
```

Please provide a solution with an explanation, if it's possible.